# How can I Hide Empty Folder when fetching Data of SDCard From Android Application?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I Have created one application in which i have to access my **SDcard** 
 memory from the application. in that What should i do to hide all empty folders?

So its easy to get relevant data faster.

Comment: pls be elaborate and post some code ? where do you want to hide empty folders ? in your app ?

Comment: what did you tried yet? share your code?

Comment: Rename the folder starts with "." for example `.Neha`

Comment: I am listing a all files using this code line.. 

File[] files = f.listFiles(); 

So now after this i want to hide all Empty folder and hidden folders from my listing..

Comment: Just calculate the size of each folder if it is greater than 0 then show it else hide that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  File [] files=f.listFiles();
  if(!files[i].length==0 && !files[i].isHidden())
{
         //perform your operation here
}
```

using this way you can ignore hidden and empty folders.